How do I have a custom logging configuration package that plays nice with 3rd party packages?
The standard way of instantiating a logger is at the module level (from what I understand), so I assume most 3rd party packages do this:
# consider this somepackage
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
def blah():
    logger.info("slkdjflksjfkld")
...

But I want my applications to configure their project wide logging with a shared package
What happens is after my imports fileConfig is called and logging, formatting, etc is setup from scratch and it blows away any module level loggers that were in the imported packages.
So for example if somepackage instantiated logging like above and I do this:
# logging.getLogger() is going to be called immediately
from somepackage import blah

# Import my logging config package and get a logger
from mycomp.logging import get_logger
logger = get_logger(my custom params)

My get_logger() function configures project wide logging and it removes the handlers from somepackage.
But if I do it in this order somepackage will get my global logging config correctly:
# FIRST Import my logging config package and get a logger before anything else
from mycomp.logging import get_logger
logger = get_logger(my custom params)

# Now logging.getLogger() picks up my custom global logging config
from somepackage import blah

Am I missing something about how this works? Maybe 3rd party packages don't actually instantiate loggers on import and implement some kind of singleton? But from what I see in the wild they seem to do it at the module level.
